# Authenticate to K8s cluster through AWS Lambda

Tags: kubernetes, aws-lambda

We are using the following to authenticate:

```
import base64
import boto3
import string
import random
from botocore.signers import RequestSigner


class EKSAuth(object):
    METHOD = 'GET'
    EXPIRES = 60
    EKS_HEADER = 'x-k8s-aws-id'
    EKS_PREFIX = 'k8s-aws-v1.'
    STS_URL = 'sts.amazonaws.com'
    STS_ACTION = 'Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15'

    def __init__(self, cluster_id, region='us-east-1'):
        self.cluster_id = cluster_id
        self.region = region

    def get_token(self):
        """
        Return bearer token
        """
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        # Get ServiceID required by class RequestSigner
        client = session.client("sts", region_name=self.region)
        service_id = client.meta.service_model.service_id

        signer = RequestSigner(
            service_id,
            session.region_name,
            'sts',
            'v4',
            session.get_credentials(),
            session.events
        )

        params = {
            'method': self.METHOD,
            'url': 'https://' + self.STS_URL + '/?' + self.STS_ACTION,
            'body': {},
            'headers': {
                self.EKS_HEADER: self.cluster_id
            },
            'context': {}
        }

        signed_url = signer.generate_presigned_url(
            params,
            region_name=session.region_name,
            expires_in=self.EXPIRES,
            operation_name=''
        )

        return (
                self.EKS_PREFIX +
                base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
                    signed_url.encode('utf-8')
                ).decode('utf-8')
        )
```

And then we call this by

```
KUBE_FILEPATH = '/tmp/kubeconfig'
CLUSTER_NAME = 'cluster'
REGION = 'us-east-2'

if not os.path.exists(KUBE_FILEPATH):
    kube_content = dict()
    # Get data from EKS API
    eks_api = boto3.client('eks', region_name=REGION)
    cluster_info = eks_api.describe_cluster(name=CLUSTER_NAME)
    certificate = cluster_info['cluster']['certificateAuthority']['data']
    endpoint = cluster_info['cluster']['endpoint']

    kube_content = dict()

    kube_content['apiVersion'] = 'v1'
    kube_content['clusters'] = [
        {
            'cluster':
                {
                    'server': endpoint,
                    'certificate-authority-data': certificate
                },
            'name': 'kubernetes'

        }]

    kube_content['contexts'] = [
        {
            'context':
                {
                    'cluster': 'kubernetes',
                    'user': 'aws'
                },
            'name': 'aws'
        }]

    kube_content['current-context'] = 'aws'
    kube_content['Kind'] = 'config'
    kube_content['users'] = [
        {
            'name': 'aws',
            'user': 'lambda'
        }]

    # Write kubeconfig
    with open(KUBE_FILEPATH, 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(kube_content, outfile, default_flow_style=False)

    # Get Token
    eks = auth.EKSAuth(CLUSTER_NAME)
    token = eks.get_token()
    print("Token here:")
    print(token)
    # Configure
    config.load_kube_config(KUBE_FILEPATH)
    configuration = client.Configuration()
    configuration.api_key['authorization'] = token
    configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
    # API
    api = client.ApiClient(configuration)
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api(api)

    print("THIS IS GETTING 401!!")
    ret = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='default')
```

However, this is getting the error in the Lambda:

> [ERROR] ApiException: (401) Reason: Unauthorized

Is there some type of way I have to generate the ~/.aws/credentials or config? I believe this might be why it is not able to authenticate?

Comment: EKS authentication comes in _(at least)_ two forms: the User or Role who created the cluster, and then the contents of [`kubectl -n kube-system get cm -o yaml aws-auth`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html#aws-auth-configmap); have you already verified that your lambda is using one or both of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `EKSAuth` class works. Just checked it with my cluster.

Here is a working (simpler) snippet instead of the second one.

```
import base64
import tempfile
import kubernetes
import boto3
from auth import EKSAuth


cluster_name = "my-cluster"

# Details from EKS
eks_client = boto3.client('eks')
eks_details = eks_client.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)['cluster']

# Saving the CA cert to a temp file (working around the Kubernetes client limitations)
fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
ca_filename = fp.name
cert_bs = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(eks_details['certificateAuthority']['data'].encode('utf-8'))
fp.write(cert_bs)
fp.close()

# Token for the EKS cluster
eks_auth = EKSAuth(cluster_name)
token = eks_auth.get_token()

# Kubernetes client config
conf = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
conf.host = eks_details['endpoint']
conf.api_key['authorization'] = token
conf.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
conf.ssl_ca_cert = ca_filename
k8s_client = kubernetes.client.ApiClient(conf)

# Doing something with the client
v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(k8s_client)
print(v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces())
```

* Most of the code is taken form [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2309#issue-571897943)

And you also have to make sure you've granted permission for the IAM role your lambda run with in the eks cluster.
For that run:

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth
```

Add this lines under `mapRoles`. `rolearn` is the arn of your role. `username` is the name you want to give to that role inside the k8s cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    # Add this #######################################
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/myLambda-role-z71amo5y
      username: my-lambda-mapped-user
    ####################################################
```

And create a `clusterrolebinding` or `rolebinding` to grant this user permissions inside the cluster.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user my-lambda-mapped-user  my-clusterrolebinding
```